# show hide of rows inside a helper in a rails project

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am running a loop in my helper method.

Which gives me a result like after 6 items the row closes and then for next 6 items another row gets created and this goes on.

Now I want to have another condition where If there's more than 2 rows, I don't want to show the third or fourth loop, instead I want to put a link/button which says show more and on Its click display other items.

here's the code

```
 part_child_option.  each_slice(6) do | six_o|
  html += "<div class = 'row'>"
  six_o.each do |o|
  html += "<div class='col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper'>"
  html += "<label class = 'p_name' for='#{attr_name}'>"
    html += image_tag o.photo(:small), class: "tick_option_img"
      html += "</label>"
      html += "</div>"
   end 
      html += "</div>"
   end
 html.html_safe
```

Any idea on this. Can we put a condition like if `count>2`, hide remaining rows and on click show all.

Answer (score 1):

please elaborate your problem and show some code from views. question is what you want to do when one click "More+" button (want to open new index page or load only remaining rows via ajax).

According to available description I would suggest you to put a `link_to more, items_path` and redirect on index page of all items.

UPDATE:
your each row contain 6 elements and by default there are 2 rows mean 12 elements are there. so, replace your `each_slice` loop with `each_slice_with_index` and put `if` condition.

e.g

```
part_child_option.  each_slice_with_index(6) do | six_o , i|
  if i <= 1      
      html += "<div class = 'row'>"
      six_o.each do |o|
      html += "<div class='col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper'>"
      html += "<label class = 'p_name' for='#{attr_name}'>"
        html += image_tag o.photo(:small), class: "tick_option_img"
          html += "</label>"
          html += "</div>"
       end 
          html += "</div>"
   elsif i == 2
      show link here 
      html += same code as above with hidden class added 
   else
      html += same code as above with hidden class added
   end
 end
```

I suggest take some code of row making to smaller methods to make this helper simple.

Comment: Want to show the remaining rows on click of show more.

Comment: on load I want to show only two rows and a show more button and on click to that button, the remaining rows.

This is what I am trying 

`$(window).load(function () {
 $(".class1 > div").next().next().css('visibility','hidden');`  and then

`$('.button_click').click(function(){
   $(".selected_part_child > div").next().next().css('visibility','visible');
 })`

This is working. How can I add the show more button to only places where there are more than two rows??

I am simply adding a anchor on my page then It comes to all the places


Hope it is clear now

Comment: I updated your existing code i think it can help you to make some logic.